# Remap key for entire application

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

my problem is i want to remap the numeric pad dot key to the system decimal separator for my entire application.

So if the user has a comma has decimal separator then when the users press the numpad dot my app will show the comma instead.

I can get the separator from:

```
System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator;
```

it is possible to alter the currentculture to do this? or there is another way?

Comment: Won't people who have different decimal separators have different keyboard layouts? Not all of them, of course, but a good amount.

Comment: In appropriate places You can just detect that user pressed a *dot* and replace it with a *comma*. If this behaviour is, for example, desired for text boxes in Your application, You can create Your own text box control derived from the original `TextBox` and implement the behaviour there, so You have it in one place and in reusable form.

Comment: Sounds like a *really* bad hack around having the Thread.CurrentCulture set wrong.  Your user already knows the difference between a comma and a decimal point, don't mess with his keyboard.  Just make sure that *you* know the difference.

Comment: @gunr2171 the numeric pad dot button is always a dot, in my culture the decimal separator is comma.

Comment: @LukaszM i think maybe creating my own controls can solve this issue...

Comment: Let me know if I can post my comment as answer or if You would like some more information on how to implement this.

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i solved, i found the solution in [msdn](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Replace-numpad-decimalpoint-c1e0e6cd) but is for vb.net so i translated to c#

first i put the following code in my Program.cs class, (so this will affect the entire app):

```
if (System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator != ".")
            System.Windows.Forms.Application.AddMessageFilter(new DecimalConverterFilter());
```

then you need to create the decimalconverterfilter class:

```
internal class DecimalConverterFilter : IMessageFilter
{

    private const uint WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
    {

        if (m.Msg == WM_KEYDOWN)
        {
            Keys toets = (Keys)Convert.ToInt32(m.WParam.ToInt32() & (int)Keys.KeyCode);
            if (toets == Keys.Decimal)
            {
                SendKeys.Send(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

and now every time that the decimal dot button (the button between "0" and "enter") is pressed, the "dot" is converted to the currentculture decimal separator.

In msdn says that the AddMessageFilter can degrade performance but i haven't notice so far...